# iPhone:Problem when submitting the app which has same bundle identifier

Tags: iphone

I have created a provisional profile using 'Non Wild Card App ID'. Which does have like "com.compnayname.appname". As i want to use this for my free application as well as the same application with new set of features as paid application, i followed to not to use Wild Card App ID. Now i have submitted my free application, it is being shown well. I am trying to submit the same app which has more features, as paid application, iTunes connect throws error as "The binary you uploaded was invalid. The bundle identifier is already in use by a different software package.". I used the same bundle identifier for paid app build too when creating Distribution build, because provisional profile is created same for both the apps. I also tried to create a build using "com.compnayname.appname.moreinfo", but app building is not successful as Prov Profile is being created with "com.compnayname.appname".
What can i do now? How would i use the same provisional profile and bundle identifier for my same free app and paid app? Then what is the use of creating  'Non Wild Card App ID' ??

Note: I know creating of Wild Card ID and use it. But i wanted to use Non-Wild Card ID for both the apps(but same app), free app and paid app.

Could someone please help me on resolving this?

Thank you. Appreciate your quick help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's the same app, use the same ID, but make it an "upgrade" from your previous app, that is, use the "upgrade this application" button in iTunes Connect.  This will mean people who downloaded it before for free will get the new version for free, but you can charge new users if you want.

If you don't want previous owners to get the new version for free, then it's really a new app, and needs a new bundle ID.

Another option is to make it an upgrade, leave it free, and use in-app-purchase to unlock the new features.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that if you are building a suite of apps that should share the same settings etc. then you should be using a wildcard app ID.

I don't believe it's possible to use a unique appID for two apps. Then it wouldn't be unique.